# Error on S3 web console launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I got an AWS free account for one year.
I've created a S3 instance yesterday, and today when I try to connect with my Google Chrome browser at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=eu-central-1 I got and error

> {   "errorCode" : "InternalError" }

instead of any web page...

Anybody knows how can I find help ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clear cookies.
2. Use another browser.
3. Check your personal health dashboard at https://phd.aws.amazon.com
4. Since S3 is "global" you can try changing region (i.e. https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=eu-west-1), your buckets should still be visible to you.

Comment: Sorry but I have no issues in the Event log, changing region doesn't help. Cookies cleared, and with Firefox and Brave, I got the same :-(

Comment: Such things happen sometimes when AWS engineers deploy updates (and they do roll out new S3 interface now). So just try again later.